# Efficiently detect corrupted jpeg file?

Tags: php, jpeg, corruption

Is there an efficient way of detecting if a jpeg file is corrupted?

Background info:
  solutions needs to work from within a php script
  the jpeg files are on disk
  manual checking is no option (user uploaded data)

I know that `imagecreatefromjpeg(string $filename);` can do it. But it is quite slow at doing so.

Does anybody know a faster/more efficient solutions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the command line you can use jpeginfo to find out if a jpeg file is OK or not.

> $ jpeginfo -c test.jpeg
>
> test.jpeg  260 x 264  24bit JFIF  N   15332  [OK]

It should be trivial to call jpeginfo from php.

Comment: note the remark from the OP about slow: forking an external process and process the return is possibly even slower than imagecreatefromjpeg()!

Comment: You might be right, I have no idea how slow imagecreatefromjpeg is. I suppose the only way to find it to benchmark both.

Comment: Although forking an external process is slow, it is the better option. PHP is awful in it's memory requirements and speed when reading image files. See also [Travis' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198438/efficiently-detect-corrupted-jpeg-file/2761021#2761021).

Comment: `identify` from ImageMagick will also detect corrupt JPEG files.

Comment: `jpeginfo -c ./*.jpg | grep ERROR` will find all the corrupted files efficiently

Comment: Thanks. I tried identify from ImageMagick and while it does works it's slow.

Comment: identify works... you can use it in a directory with a command such as `identify * |grep insufficient` to find dodgy jpegs assuming all files are jpegs, otherwise *.jpeg for only jpegs of course...

Comment: @RogerLipscombe - I've generally found that ImageMagick is able to successfully read corrupted JPEG files that many other applications are unable to, so it's not the most reliable test. Specifically, it reads truncated JPEGs without issue, which is the most likely problem in this scenario.

Answer (score 9):

My simplest (and fastest) solution:

```
function jpeg_file_is_complete($path) {
    if (!is_resource($file = fopen($path, 'rb'))) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    // check for the existence of the EOI segment header at the end of the file
    if (0 !== fseek($file, -2, SEEK_END) || "\xFF\xD9" !== fread($file, 2)) {
        fclose($file);
        return FALSE;
    }
    fclose($file);
    return TRUE;
}

function jpeg_file_is_corrupted($path) {
    return !jpeg_file_is_complete($path);
}
```

Note: This only detects a corrupted file structure, but does NOT detect corrupted image data.

Comment: This is indeed fast, but does not detect incomplete data (shown as a black lower part of the jpeg image).

Comment: Really nice to find images that were not transfered completely.

Comment: This method is fast but is not accurate. Valid JPEG can have bytes at the end after FFD9 and invalid JPEG can end with FFD9. So this method gives false positives and positive negatives.

Answer (score 7):

FYI -- I've used [the method above (`jpeg_file_is_complete`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622536/15619) to test JPEGs which I know are corrupt (when I load them in a browser, for example, the bottom is gray -- i.e., the image is "cut off"). Anyhow, when I ran the above test on that image it DID NOT detect it as corrupt.

So far, using `imagecreatefromjpeg()` works, but is not very fast. I found that using `jpeginfo` works as well to detect these types of corrupt images, and is FASTER than `imagecreatefromjpeg` (I ran a benchmark in my PHP using `microtime()`).

Comment: thanks, checking the jpeg_file_is_complete() functionality was still on my list of things to do. saves me the time :)

Comment: A quick follow-up. I've been successfully using "jpeginfo" to test JPGs and it has worked great. It's fast and does not give false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
<?php
$img = $_GET['img'];
$str_exec = 'jpeginfo -c /chroot/home/www/html/media/'.$img;
$result = exec($str_exec);
if(strpos($result, 'ERROR'))
{
    echo 'ERROR';
}
else
{
    echo 'OK';
}
?>
```

Comment: Watch out if using this on a public webserver: You are passing the input from GET directly to the command line, allowing an easy shell exploit: What if I call the above page with `?img= rm - rf .` ? It will probably delete all files in the current dir

Answer (score 0):

**Just a small note- how to get jpeginfo for Windows (64 bit)?**
There are no win32/win64 binaries on author's github but you can do this:

1) grab `jpeginfo.exe` from this archive: 
https://github.com/MoserMichael/cstuff/raw/master/img-archive/img-archive.zip

2) grab `cygwin1.dll` from this archive:
ftp://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/cygwin/x86/release/cygwin64/cygwin64-2.6.0-1.tar.xz

Test it from commandline if it works: `jpeginfo --help`. If there is info- it works just fine.

**How to test jpeginfo output?**

`jpeginfo` returns 0 if the file is ok but it returns 1 not only when it's not but also when it found something it doesn't understand. Then it generates a message like this:

`Warning: unknown JFIF revision number 2.01 1280 x 720  24bit JFIF  N  122550  [WARNING]`

On corrupted files it returns 1 and message like this:

`1328 x 2048 24bit JFIF  N 1310080  Premature end of JPEG file  [WARNING]`

Therefore you might want to test the actual output not only return code.

Answer (score -1):

You may also try to generate file hash based on MD5 and use it as checksum to validate JPEG data on various steps. For example, after read from file, then after transfer, etc.

Comment: This would work for moving the file around internally, not for detecting files that are corrupted before entering the system.

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

I found the perfect tool for what I needed:

http://www.thomasbarker.co.uk/2011/05/29/corrupt-jpeg-checkertool-for-finding-corrupt-jpeg-image-files/

Searches recursively through a directory and finds any corrupted JPEGS. Looks like you can use as many CPUs as you like to do it also.

Worked for me.

Comment: This is now https://www.barkersoftware.com/support/corrupt-jpeg-checker-gui-for-windows-xp-7-8/ and apparently only wraps [libjpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg), just like [jpeginfo](https://github.com/tjko/jpeginfo) does. _libjpeg_ fails to detect **all** corrupt files.

Answer (score -3):

I have an other solution with a simply getimagesize()

```
if(!getimagesize($image_url)) echo 'Image is corrupt or not readable';
```

Comment: corrupt exif data can corrupt the rest of the file but won't be caught by this method.

Comment: From the PHP doc: [*"**Caution**
This function expects filename to be a valid image file. If a non-image file is supplied, it may be incorrectly detected as an image and the function will return successfully, but the array may contain nonsensical values.
Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image. Use a purpose-built solution such as the Fileinfo extension instead."*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)