# How to detect corrupt very large image files with javascript and jquery-file-upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery-file-upload in a rails app and I need to prevent corrupted images from being uploaded because users are trying to upload corrupt image files with valid file extensions.

Would like to verify client side using javascrpt to avoid the long delay for verification on server with large files over 50 MB.

I can check the file type but how would I reliably verify a very large valid and uncorrupted jpg or tif image using jquery/native javascript/jquery-file-upload?

```
$('form[id*=photo]').fileupload({
  dataType: 'script',
  pasteZone: null,
  sequentialUploads: true,
  formData: {fileupload: 'ajax'},
  add: function(e, data) {
    if($('#photo_id').val() == ""){
        data.type = 'POST';
    }else{
        data.type = 'PUT';
        data.url = "/photos/" + $('#photo_id').val();
    }
    if(this.id != "new_photo"){
        data.type = 'PUT';
    }
    types = /(\.|\/)(jpe?g|tif|tiff)$/i;
    file = data.files[0];
     if( types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name) ) {
        data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file));
        $('.upload').remove();           
        $('#progbar').append(data.context);
        $('#control-group-progress').show();
        data.submit();
     } else {
         alert("We're sorry but the file " + file.name + " is not in a supported tiff or jpg image file format.  Please select a jpeg (jpg) or tiff file.  Thanks!");
     }
  },
  progress: function(e, data) {
   if(data.context) {
      progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
      progress = parseInt(progress * 0.9, 10);
      data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%');    
      data.context.find('.progress_percent').html(progress + "%");    
    }
  },
  always: function(e, data) {
    data.context.find('.bar').css('width', '100%');    
    data.context.find('.progress_percent').html("100%");
  }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198438/efficiently-detect-corrupted-jpeg-file

Comment: Thanks Robert!  Great server side and desktop solutions with interesting approaches.  Not sure if any are feasible for browser based client side javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You can try following JavaScript code for verifying file type and file size

```
var uploadedImgType = $('#photo_id').val();
file = data.files[0];
if(uploadedImgType.match(/(?:jpeg|jpg|tif|tiff)$/) && (file.size/1000/1000 < 50)){
  (Do your Stuff);
}else{
  alert("We're sorry but the file " + file.name + " is not in a supported tiff or jpg image file format.  Please select a jpeg (jpg) or tiff file.  Thanks!");
}
```

where **file.size/1000/1000 < 50** will check whether uploaded file has size less than 50MB.

Comment: Thanks! How can I verify if image file is corrupt before the upload?

Comment: I am not sure how to check corrupted/broken file uploading through JavaScript, but you may do this through server side by checking MIME Type of a file

`type = MIME::Types.type_for(your_file.original_filename).first`

as written in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1229600/2230932, please refer this.

Comment: I am also looking for corrupt image file detection from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var getDataUrl = function (blob) {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        defer.resolve(e.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      return defer.promise;
    };

    file = data.files[0];

    getDataUrl(file).then(function (dataUrl) {
      var uploadedImg = new Image();
      uploadedImg.src = dataUrl;
      if (uploadedImg.width && uploadedImg.height) {
        // image is OK
      } else {
        // Image is corrupted
      }
    });
```